# Setting the background color of persp() plots

Tags: r, plot

Is there any way to set the background color of plots constructed using the base R function `persp()`?

`bg="black"` is ignored either when supplied to `persp()` or previously to `par()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "ignored" here. A reproducible example would be helpful, something like this:

```
 par(bg = "black");persp(volcano)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't provide more information, and I must now sheepishly admit I cannot reproduce the problem I was having two days ago. For the record, the problem with persp() was that when I specified z data only, I could set the background color, but not when I supplied x, y & z data.  I'm having no such problem now, so my apologies and if the problem recurs I'll be sure to copy the exact code.